# Changing password from US Keyboard to Norwegian Keyboard

Tags: password, keyboard-layout

I just did a test install on my computer with Ubuntu 16.10.
I encrypted the drive with a yubikey static key, and finished the installation with norwegian keyboard settings.

On initial launch after installation the key/passphrase did not match. I found a thread telling me to install using US Keyboard, and then change keyboard layout once inside ubuntu. I did, and the passphrase now works.

Now, the password i used for my user includes a `&`, witch on a norwegian keyboard is `Shift + 6`. On a US keyboard thats the `^`. This is all well and good, knowing this I logged in and changed the keyboard layout.

Now I'm trying to change the password for my user, typing the password with `^` and trying to change it to `&`. I used `sudo passwd` in the terminal, and it returned successful. But the password has not changed - the `^` is still needed to log in and do sudo commands.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change your password, do not use the `sudo` with the command. Simply use `passwd` and change the password. This should solve your problem. Another way would be the following command.

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I knew it had to be something stupid like that. Worked like a charm.